# Corba,running Hello World on two machines

Tags: java, corba, idl

I'm trying to run a simple client-server program on two machines ,

I read this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/idl/tutorial/jidl2machines.html) but i got this errors :

```
Jun 04, 2012 6:43:10 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectio
nImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR
_TEXT; hostname: xx.xx.xx.xx; port: 1050"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(Unknown Source)
        at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more

ERROR : org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No

org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(Unknown Source)
        at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
```

Could you please let me know how can i run a simple program like " Hello Wrold " on two machines over internet using Corba and java?

Regards.

Comment: Have you check firewall? When you run `java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050` check by `netstat -na` (check syntax on windows) if server is listen on 1050. Then run client.

Comment: i checked it. sever is listening on port 1050.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i run a simple program like " Hello Wrold " on two machines over internet using Corba and java?

I think **over the internet** is key here. You need to make sure that:

1. the server is accessible to the client on the **IP address** you specify (i.e. either the IP address is public, or there are appropriate masquarading rules set up on any relevant firewalls);
2. there are appropriate firewall and/or port forwarding rules that allow the client to access **port 1050** on the server.

I would recommend to first get the client and the server working when run on the same subnet, and only then move on to a distributed setup.

Comment: Did you mean i run server and client on the same machine?i ran this program on one machine.it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run orb `start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050`
2. Run your class client and server with: `-ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost`

or alternative:
1. Run server:
tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050

2. Run client:
   java YourServer -ORBInitialPort 1050
   java YourClient -ORBInitialHost 127.0.0.1 -ORBInitialPort 1050

[a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218532/corba-orbd-error/37576507#37576507)