# Corba ORBD error

Tags: java, distributed-computing, corba

I am developing a simple Remote Administration Tool using CORBA. This is my server code.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package simrat;

import SimRATApp.SimRAT;
import SimRATApp.SimRATHelper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.omg.CORBA.ORB;
import org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExt;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtHelper;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.CannotProceed;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POA;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAHelper;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage.AdapterInactive;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage.ServantNotActive;
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage.WrongPolicy;

/**
 *
 * @author Rumesh
 */
public class Server {

    public SimRATMain sim;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("orbd -ORBInitialPort 1059 -port 1032 -ORBInitialHost localhost");

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //String[] args = {};
            ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);

            POA rootpoa = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
            rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

            SimRATImpl impl = new SimRATImpl();
            impl.setORB(orb);

            org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootpoa.servant_to_reference(impl);
            SimRAT href = SimRATHelper.narrow(ref);

            org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

            NameComponent path[] = ncRef.to_name("SimRAT");
            ncRef.rebind(path, href);

            System.out.println("Server Ready and waiting...");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server created successfully", "SimRAT Server", 1);

            orb.run();





        } catch (InvalidName ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (AdapterInactive ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (ServantNotActive ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (WrongPolicy ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (NotFound ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (CannotProceed ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server creation failed", "SimRAT Server", 1);
        }


    }
}
```

But when I try to run the program I get following error.

```
Jun 14, 2014 2:54:04 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.1.33; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2200)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2221)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1170)
    at simrat.Server.main(Server.java:125)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:364)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:356)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:623)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:184)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:206)
    ... 11 more
```

I tried changing

`-ORBInitialHost localhost` to `-ORBInitialHost 192.168.1.33`

But the error remains. Can anyone suggest me a solution to get orbd started.

Comment: Have you started the 'orbd' program?

Comment: I am starting the orbd program with this line. That is the line which error occurs.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("orbd -ORBInitialPort 1059 -port 1032 -ORBInitialHost localhost");

Comment: No it isn't. See the stack trace. Runtime.exec() doesn't appear in it anywhere. It happens when you call resolve_initial_references().

Comment: Seems it is not executing. I try to start orbd in the command prompt and got the same error. Do you know why?

Comment: You got the same error from this program, or from orbd? and why are you specifying all those ports to orbd but not to your own code! Try it without all the port arguments.

Comment: From orbd also I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run orb in console your system start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050
2. Run YourServer.java -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost
3. Run YourClient.java -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost

great tutorial:
[Tutorial for CORBA Hello World using Java](http://www.ejbtutorial.com/programming/tutorial-for-corba-hello-world-using-java)

Comment: Thanks. I even forgot that I asked this question on SO. :D :D